# How to make a html table appear using ajax and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Ive been trying to make my html table appear when i click the submit button but all it does is inserts data into the database and the html table doesnt appear.

here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("table.php");
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action = "insert.php" method="post">
      Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname"></br>
      Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname"></br>
      Middlename: <input type="text" name="middlename"></br>
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    <div id="div1">
    </div>      
  </body>
</html>
```

here is my table.php

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","study");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) 
{
  echo "Failed to connect to mysql" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

echo '<table border = 1>';
echo '<tr>';
echo ' <th>FIRSTNAME</th>';
echo '<th>LASTNAME</th>';
echo ' <th>MIDDLENAME</th>';
echo ' <th>DELETE</th>';
echo ' </tr>';
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sample_employers");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['middlename'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td> <input type='button' value='Delete' </td>"; 
  echo "</tr>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
echo '</table>';
?>
```

I did some editing in my index.php. I put the submit button outside the form tag and the html table appears but the problem now is there is no data inserted to the database.So how am i going to make the html table appear and at the same time insert data to the database when i click the submit button.??

Comment: If you run table.php by itself does it return anything?

Comment: @Nick yes..the table appear when i run the table.php

Comment: Why did you move the form and submit button?

Comment: @Paul what do you mean??I moved the submit button to try if it will work..

Comment: If you're using firefox or chrome check to see if the request is actually being made.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, and I guess I'm not sure what is the question.  The title asks about making a table appear using ajax.  You seem to be doing that correctly.  But then at the bottom you say you made the table appear but now the submit button doesn't work. If you want a table inside a form, that's generally OK.  You can also have multiple forms with different action statements or ajax posters and maybe one or none of them involves the table.  But it seems we're not on the original topic any more.

Comment: Can it be it be that you are redirected on `insert.php` after you hit submit when the button is inside the form? My theory is you will have to prevent the redirect.

Comment: I agree with @k0pernikus. Additionally I think you'd probably want to use ajax if you don't want the form to redirect after submitting the form and to load your table.php.

Answer (score 0):

```
// example 1 GET
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submitButt").click(function(e){    // u should give a id to the button. 
    e.preventDefault();    // this is to prevent the form submit by it self

    // using ajax to submit
    $("#div1").load("insert.php",
        $(this.form).serialize();    // this will use GET to submit data
    );
  });
});

// example 2 POST
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submitButt").click(function(e){    // u should give a id to the button. 
    e.preventDefault();    // this is to prevent the form submit by it self

    // using ajax to submit
    $("#div1").load("insert.php",
        $(this.form).serializeArray();    // this will use POST to submit data
    );
  });
});


http://jsfiddle.net/9kcek/
```

use Tamper Data to check the request when u click the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

If you press submit, then you will be redirected to `insert.php`. Hence, your click event will never be executed. You must prevent the redirect first in order for you to load your data.

Furthermore, you will need to switch the way in which your data is posted. As you want to directly insert the table on the current page, you should switch to an ajax approach. Your data will be sent to your `insert.php` in the background via `$.ajax` and then you can load your `#div1` on success with the content of `table.php`.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $form = $('form');
        $form.submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var formData = $form.serialize(),
                url = $form.attr('action');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: formData,
                success: function () {
                    $("#div1").load("table.php");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks..but what does this code mean?? 

var formData = $form.serialize(),
                url = $form.attr('action');

Comment: @jmjassy27 `$form.serialize()` converts the form data into an url-encoded string, which you then can post. `$form.attr('action')` reads the attribute `action` of your form tag, which in your case is `insert.php`. It is the url to which the data shall be posted. Don't be confused by the comma-seperation. For further reference see [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: @jmjassy27 My code resembles pretty much the example on [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).